# Nest Js Graphql Resolve Field with Circular Dependency

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, nestjs

I have a problem with a circular dependency in a GraphQL model.
I'm using Nestjs Graphql MongoDb Mongoose ad I have 3 entities.

```
@ObjectType()
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {
     @Field(() => ID)
     _id: string;
     @Field({ nullable: true })
     @Prop({ nullable: true, unique: true })
     pseudoDiscord?: string;
}
```

```
@ObjectType()
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class UserGame {
     @Field(() => ID)
     _id: string;

     @Field(() => User)
     @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
     userId: User;
}
```

```
@ObjectType()
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class UserGameRole {
    @Field(() => ID)
    _id: string;

    @Field(() => UserGame)
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserGame' })
    userGameId: UserGame;

    otherField...
}
```

```
query {
  findAllUserGameRole {
    _id
    userGameId {
      pseudoInGame
      userId {
        pseudoDiscord
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to create a field named **userGame** in the user entity so that I can extract information from this entity.
How do I do this? I need to import the UserGame module into User to access the UserGameService and make requests, but the UserGameModule already imports the UserModule to resolve **userId **fields.
When I start from the UserGameRole and go back up to the UserGame and then to the User with a GraphQL query, the information received is null.

Comment: Circular dependencies between types are quite common and even expected in GraphQL. Could you post the actual gql query you are attempting to run?

Comment: I've modified the post by adding the query. 
Here's an example of a query I'm trying to execute, the pseudoDiscord field returns null like this.
But I haven't made a resolveField for the userId in the userGameResolver, so if you tell me that circular dependencies are common, I'll go with that.